# Prevent Syntax tree action from being performed on each file of opened solution

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I have a code analyzer with an action registered to syntax tree parsing:

```
public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
{
    context.RegisterSyntaxTreeAction(HandleSyntaxTree);
}
```

Problem is that when opening a solution, it is performed for each (*.cs) file of the solution. Since the `HandleSyntaxTree()` method calls a command line process of Git, for a large solution this gets **very** slow.

Is there a way how to have `HandleSyntaxTree()` invoked only for file opened in the editor?

---

**EDIT: Semi-pseudo-code of the HandleSyntaxTree()  method**

```
    private void HandleSyntaxTree(SyntaxTreeAnalysisContext context)
    {
        vart root = context.Tree.GetCompilationUnitRoot(context.CancellationToken);
        string filePath = context.Tree.FilePath;

        GetGitCurrentBranchName(filePath); //**** Calls Git ****

        if (!availableHashBasedDescriptionOfCurrentlyEditedFile)
        {                
            ExportFileFromGitRepoToTemporaryLocation(filePath); //**** Calls Git ****
            CreateHashBasedDescriptionOfCurrentlyEditedFile();
        }

        var declarationNodes = GetSpecifiedDeclarationNodesFromSyntaxRoot(root);

        foreach (var node in declarationNodes )
        {
            if (!NodeDiffersFromGitRepo(node)) continue;
            if (NodeContainsRequiredTagInComment(node)) continue;

            FindTokenAndReportDiagnostics(context, node);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you describe your end-to-end scenario? That'll make it easier to give better advice.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski: I have added a psedo-code of the HandleSyntaxTree() method - is that sufficient?

Comment: Ah, so you're trying to build somewhere where certain changes require additional commenting, like a "change history" comment in the top?